# How do I get the indices from the Tkinter textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to be able to get the index (like 1.1...) out of a highlighted text in a Tkinter text box, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the index..."? Do you want to get the character(s) at a given index? Or are you asking about how to get the start and end index of a block of text that has been selected?

Comment: I mean the start and the end index of a selected textblock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selected text has the tag "sel". The beginning and ending range of the selected text is defined by `"sel.first"` and `"sel.last"`. You can use those directly if you want to get the text, like so:

```
chars = the_text_widget.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
```

If, instead, you want the numerical index, you can use the `index` method which converts any index to its canonical form:

```
s0 = the_text_widget.index("sel.first")
s1 = the_text_widget.index("sel.last")
```

Note: the tkinter module defines constants for these: `SEL_FIRST` and `SEL_LAST` but I personally see no reason to use these constants. Using their string counterparts is just as easy and helps reinforce the notion that the selection is just another tag without any special properties.

Comment: Should .indx not be .index()  I tried to edit but because this idiotic rule "at least 6 charachters edit" I won't do it because everything else seems ok.

Comment: @Module_art: yes, thank you for pointing that out.