# How to get the current word in tkinter's TextWidget

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose I have the following `TextField` set up in `tkinter`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TextField(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master

        s = tk.Scrollbar(master)
        text = tk.Text(master, height = 40, width = 100)
        s.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        text.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.Y)
        s.config(command=text.yview)
        text.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)

        text.insert(tk.END, "some string")
        text.bind('<Tab>', self.tabbed_text)

        self.text = text

    def tabbed_text(self, event):
        print(event)
        # now what to do here?

root=tk.Tk()
tf = TextField(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How do I get the current "word" (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`) being typed in the `tabbed_text()` function? The final aim is to have some kind of autotext functionality when hitting Tab.

Comment: Read about [Indexes - CURRENT](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: I believe you are looking for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055166/how-do-i-get-the-indices-from-the-tkinter-textbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text widget allows you to add modifiers to an index in order to adjust the index. These modifiers are `linestart`, `lineend`, `wordstart`, and `wordend`. They do pretty much what it sounds like they do.

Thus, to get the word based on the insertion cursor (index of `"insert"`) you can do it like this:

```
word = event.widget.get("insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
```

You probably also want your event handler to return the string `"break"` so that it doesn't insert a tab character:

```
def tabbed_text(self, event):
    word = event.widget.get("insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
    print("word:", word)
    return "break"
```

Note: if the cursor is at the end of a word, it's not considered in a word. You might need to use something like `insert -1c wordstart` if you want the word immediately before the cursor.

Comment: @Jan: I don't know what you're doing wrong, because I don't know what you're doing. Maybe the insertion cursor isn't in a word.

Comment: @Jan: yes, it can be prevented. You just have to check for that edge case and do something slightly different.

Comment: I added an offset (see my answer) which seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use self.text.get() function like this. You can modify the get arguments based on your need. I hope this will help you.

```
class TextField(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master

        s = tk.Scrollbar(master)
        text = tk.Text(master, height = 40, width = 100)
        s.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        text.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.Y)
        s.config(command=text.yview)
        text.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)

        text.insert(tk.END, "some string")
        text.bind('<Tab>', self.tabbed_text)

        self.text = text

    def tabbed_text(self, event):
        print(event)
        text = self.text.get("1.0","end")
        self.text.insert(tk.END, text)

root=tk.Tk()
tf = TextField(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Bryan's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57889235/1231450) I needed some extra functionality for newlines.
This is the code I ended up using (but am open to better suggestions):

```
def tabbed_text(self, event):
    word = event.widget.get("insert -1c wordstart", "insert")
    print("word:", word)
    offset = "+1c" if word[0] == "\n" else ""
    word = word.strip()

    try:
        new_string = self.replacements[word]
        event.widget.delete(f"insert -1c wordstart {offset}", "insert")
        event.widget.insert("insert", new_string)
    except:
        pass

    return "break"
```